Is there a way to save a file in LotusScript to a SharePoint directory?
As per the question title, I have a few LotusScript agents (scheduled) which build reports and are saved to a network share or flex drive in csv format. We are increasingly being asked to save these files directly into SharePoint, but I can't seem to find any information on the availability of API's to use, only tools to handle full migrations. Is there anyway to save a file into SharePoint directly from the LotusScript agent either natively or using an API? Any pointers would be much appreciated, thanks

I am not familiar with Sharepoint, but it apparently has an opportunity to implement REST endpoints: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service?tabs=csom
Make endpoints and make HTTP requests from your LotusScript code.

NotesHTTPRequest.post should do the trick if and only if you can send a JSON string and you can work out authentication issues. So if you can build a JSON string containing everything you need, and can hit a URL that will take that JSON screen and is authorized to act on it by attaching it where it should go, great.
Instead, I would look for other alternatives.

Maybe open up a fileshare a drive on the Domino server, and find a Microsoft way to auto-import them, or at that point you might just need a batch file that executes a robocopy command.
Maybe send email (which is architecturally horrible but it does sidestep authentication issues) if there's an easy way to email attachments into SharePoint.

If you can't get some programming or automation done on the SharePoint side and all the moving parts need to be Domino, look into creating an agent that's a REST or web services consumer.
For REST, you'll need to do at least a little bit of Java. This will show you how, but the Java code you'll want will need to upload a file will need to look more like the code provided in this answer.
For making a web services consumer... if your version of SharePoint offers it... look at the documentation at help.hcltechsw.com/.../H_INCORPORATING_WEB_SERVICES_LIBRARY.html.
